# Esconder e mostrar usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando fazer com que ao eu passar o mouse por cima de uma imagem, mostre uma que tem no figcaption, e assim que eu sair com o mouse de cima do figcaption, ele esconde o figcaption e mostra a imagem que estava.

Meu problema é que se eu clicar 1cm pra baixo do texto, ele fica como se tivesse piscando(abrindo e fechando).

Função do javascript

```js
function esconderdiv() 
{
    document.getElementById("teste").style.display = "none";
}
function mostrardiv() 
{
    document.getElementById("teste").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.grid{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: #213245;
    height: 131px;
    width: 131px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-left:30px;
    opacity: 0px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-2" > <img class="img-responsive" src="_imagens/1.png" onmouseover="mostrardiv()">
              <figcaption id="teste" class="grid" onmouseout="esconderdiv()">
                      <h3 align="center" style="color:#fff;">Biologia</h3>
                      <div align="center" class="link"><a onClick="openNav1()">Questões</a></div>
              </figcaption>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: porque nao usa o onmouseover e o onmouseout no mesmo elemento ao inves de usar um na div e outro no figcaption? Acredito que por isso ele esteja piscando, porque pode estar com o mouse em cima da div mas fora do figcaption entao acaba chamando as duas funcoes.

Comment: Antes tinha feito isso só que na img e não na div principal,agora deu certo ,era só isso,muito obrigado e desculpa qualquer incomodo.

Comment: Tente trocando o `onmouseout` por `onmouseleave`.

Comment: Oi Robson, li a pergunta e ainda não percebi o que queres mostrar quando o mouse passar por cima. Podes explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que você esteja querendo fazer é, ao passar o mouse na imagem seja exibido o `figcaption`. Para isso, você pode resolver apenas com css encapsulando tudo na tag `figure` e colocando um `hover` nesta tag. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  height: 131px;
  width: 131px;
}
img {
  background: #000;
  height: 131px;
  width: 131px;
}
figcaption {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: #213245;
  height: 131px;
  width: 131px;
  margin-top:9px;
  margin-left:30px;
  opacity: 0px;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <figure>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="_imagens/1.png">
      <figcaption>
        <h3 align="center" style="color:#fff;">Biologia</h3>
        <div align="center" class="link"><a onClick="openNav1()">Questões</a></div>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você disse:

> Estou tentando fazer com que ao eu passar o mouse por cima de uma imagem, mostre uma que tem no figcaption, e **assim que eu sair** com o mouse de cima do figcaption, ele esconde o figcaption e mostra a imagem que estava.]

O evento de mouse nesse caso é onmouseleave porque ele é um manipulador de eventos para ser disparado quando o mouse sair de um elemento ou acionar esse manipulador em um elemento.

Então fiz um código assim:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .grid{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: #213245;
    height: 131px;
    width: 131px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-left:30px;
    opacity: 0px;
}
.img-responsive{
        position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 131px;
    height: 131px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-left:30px;
    opacity: 0px;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
     <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-2" > <img class="img-responsive" src="_imagens/1.png" onmouseover="mostrardiv()">
              <figcaption id="teste" class="grid" onmouseleave="esconderdiv()">
                      <h3 align="center" style="color:#fff;">Biologia</h3>
                      <div align="center" class="link"><a onClick="openNav1()">Questões</a></div>
              </figcaption>
          </div>
     </div> 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function esconderdiv() {
    document.getElementById("teste").style.display = "none";
}

function mostrardiv() {
    document.getElementById("teste").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Criei a classe img-responsive só para que você visse melhor o evento  mas pode tirar do seu código.

Esse link: [Categoria: eventos de mouse](https://translate.google.com.br/translate?hl=pt-BR&sl=en&u=https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/&prev=search) fala sobre os eventos de mouse.

Espero ter ajudado!